# Conditional Order of Operations in C#

Tags: c#, python, conditional-statements

So I was recently going through the tutorial for Python on [CodeAcademy](http://www.codeacademy.com) and I came across this part.

### [image]

Where it instructs that Python has a set order in which it evaluates conditionals. I had never heard of anything like this before. I'm used to coding in C# and was wondering if C# has this same type of logic and what the ordering is for it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Once you know that this is called "operator precedence", it's a matter of seconds to find this reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @IMSoP I figured it was something simple like that. I kept searching for programming order of operations and was missing the mark by a long shot. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, someone needs to invent an AI system for answering those frustrating "I'm sure there's a standard term for this, but I don't know it and therefore can't search for it" moments.

Comment: Mind you, CodeAcademy should have used the standard term rather than / as well as "order of operations", then you wouldn't have been led on a wild goose chase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the order of precedence. In fact many languages have such rules implemented not just python.

The one that you are looking for can be found in Microsoft MSDN
[Here is the link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> 1. Operators are listed in descending order of precedence. If several operators appear on the same line or in a group, they have equal precedence.